# #ionic change the data key in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to update/add data on firebase. I used the Facebook login and I want to use the UserID as a key for the new data aded.

(check pict below)

The userID that I want to use it:

[image: The userID that i want to use it]

I want to replace that key with the userID:

[image: i want to replace that key with the userID]

```
 fblogin(){
this.facebook.login(['email'])
.then(res=> {
const fc = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(fc) 
    .then(fs => {

    this.facebook.api('me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,picture.width(720).height(720).as(picture_large)', []).then(profile => {
    this.newuser = {name: profile['first_name'] ,email: profile['email'],picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'],phone:''}
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
    console.log(fs.uid);
    this.db.list('/users/'+ fs.uid).update(this.newuser);
  });
```

I got this error in compilation:

> supplied parameters do not matchany signature of call target

In this line: `this.db.list('/users/'+ fs.uid).update(this.newuser);`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The FB error looks correct. You cant update on the `uid` as the user has been saved with a unique FB `id`

You do not show the code that created the `users` record in the database, but what i think you want to do is set and object when you first save the `users` record. However this could be an issue because the `user` could be saved before the return of the `uid`. I cant tell with your code snippet. Regardless, I will write the code that i think will work if the `users/` record is created at the time that of registration.

The service

```
async signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
  try {
    const result = await this.afA.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  }
}
```

So this initially creates a user without facebook, The key here is that the users FB `uid` was created and is held in the returned `result`

The component

```
this.authData.signupUser(email,password).then(userData => {
   console.log(userData) // <- this is result 
}
```

Then we create a record in FB with the `uid` returned

```
this.db.object(`users/${userData.uid}/`).set(data);
```

`.set(data)` is whatever data you want to save in the `users/uid` namespace.

So basically you need to create that user table with its `uid` namespace when the user first registers. Then you can update the user with the `uid` returned from the facebook `fs.uid`

---

With your current code you could [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the user based on the email ( because the email should be unique to all users) and then update ...

with lodash is it just

```
 let foundUser = find(this.db.list('users'),{ 'email' : fs.email }

 // and then update based on the object key

 this.db.list('/users/'+ Object.keys(foundUser)).update(this.newuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem by using:

```
this.db.object('/users/'+ fs.uid).update(this.newuser);
```

instead of :

```
this.db.list('/users/'+ fs.uid).update(this.newuser);
```

And it works correctly !
Thanks all for help.